# c++ ignoring same number in an array

Tags: c++, arrays, loops, for-loop

I have an array of random numbers, for example

```
6 5 4 4 8
```

I need to sort it and remove/ignore the same numbers while printing afterwards, so what I did is I sorted everything with `bubble sorth algorithm` and got something like this

```
4 4 5 6 8
```

Now in order to print only different numbers I wrote this `for loop`

```
for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
    if(mrst[i]!=mrst[i-1] && mrst[i]>0){
        outFile << mrst[i] << " ";
    }
}
```

My question is, the array I have is at the interval of [0:12], though the first time when I call it, it checks an array index of -1 to see if there was the same number before, but it doesn't really exist, but the value stored in there usually is a huge one, so is there a possibility that there may be stored 4 and because of it, the first number won't be printed out. If so, how to prevent it, rewrite the code so it would be optimal?

Comment: You must not dereference a (non-existing) element before the array, you're invoking undefined behavior.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, as you noted already, you cannot do the check `mrst[i] != mrst[i-1]` **in case `i == 0`.** So I'm sure you can think of a way of **not** doing that check **in exactly this case** ... (This looks very much like a homework assignment, so I'm not really willing to give you a complete solution, but I guess I hinted enough)

Note also that it's undefined behaviour to access memory outside the boundaries of an array, so what you're doing there can do anything from working correctly to crashing your program, entirely at the discretion of the compiler.

Comment: appreciate the tip, sometimes solutions can be so simple and just not be noticed, thanks

Answer (score 7):

Perhaps, you're looking for [`std::unique`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/unique) algorithm:

```
std::sort(mrst, mrst + n);
auto last = std::unique(mrst, mrst + n);

for(auto elem = mrst; elem != last; ++elem)
    outFile << *elem << " ";
```

Comment: This looks interesting and I'll give it a try, though Joey's solution seems a bit more simple and easy-going

Answer (score 1):

Basically you can read from any place in heap. So mrst[-1] may give you some garbage from the memory. But you really should avoid doing this. In your case you can just change "mrst[i]!=mrst[i-1] && mrst[i]>0" to "i==0 || mrst[i]!=mrst[i-1]".

In c++ "A || B" don't execute "B" if the "A" is ok.